# How to make a plot of all variables in dataframe with a single variable in R

Tags: r, plot

I tried making a panel plot using the code from other person's stack exchange post but I am getting errors. I feel like i have tried 100 different ways to do this and i cant get any of them to work and I am actually losing my mind. I get the error "Error: Aesthetic must be a one-sided formula, call, name, or constant." Here is the code: (I also need to check to pearson correlations of all variables with the one response so if you could help with that as well that would be great!)

## code start:

```
library(grid)
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  
  
  # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)
  
  numPlots = length(plots)
  
  # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
  if (is.null(layout)) {
    # Make the panel
    # ncol: Number of columns of plots
    # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
    layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                     ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }
  
  if (numPlots==1) {
    print(plots[[1]])
    
  } else {
    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))
    
    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
      matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
      print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}

# plot the first variable against all others
plotList <- list()
for (i in 1:99) {
plotList[[i]] <- ggplot(data = data, aes_(x = data[,100-i], y = data[100])) + geom_point() + xlab("x") + ylab("y")
}

# actually draw the multiplot
multiplot(plotlist = plotList, cols = 3)
```

I also have a different index than the original post since my variable of interest is in the last column of the dataframe not the first. here is the link to the other post: [How to plot scatterplot of a variable in a dataframe with all other variables in a single plot using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274355/how-to-plot-scatterplot-of-a-variable-in-a-dataframe-with-all-other-variables-in)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is create a small-multiples plot of one variable plotted against every other variable (all continuous) in your data, then components of the `tidyverse` (`tidyr` and `ggplot2`) are a much simpler approach then trying to manually create the grid, and seems like you're already trying to use `ggplot` in here so not constraining yourself to base R?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

# plot all numeric variables against year

longer_gapminder <- gapminder %>%
  pivot_longer(c(-year, -country, -continent),
               names_to = "variable",
               values_to = "value")

longer_gapminder %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>